# Is exercise 1.10d from Hartshorne just entirely wrong or is it salvageable in any non-trivial way?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

The question is

> (d) If $Y$ is a closed subset of an irreducible finite-dimensional topological space $X$, and if $\dim Y=\dim X$, then $Y=X$.

Here we are using this definition for dimension

> Definition. If $X$ is a topological space, we define the dimension of $X$ (denoted $\dim X$ ) to be the supremum of all integers $n$ such that there exists a chain $Z_0 \subsetneq Z_1 \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq Z_n \subsetneq X$ of distinct irreducible closed subsets of $X$.

Letting $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and $Y= \{1,2\}$ where the closed sets are $\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,2,3\}$. You can check that

- $X$ is indeed irreducible,
- $Y$ is a closed subset,
- $\dim X = \dim Y = 0$,

but clearly $Y \neq X$. You can salvage the statement by requiring $Y$ to also be irreducible but then the exercise is almost trivial. I am wondering if I am missing something here or if there's some non-trivial way you can salvage this exercise.

(Proof that $\dim X = \dim Y = 0$)
The only irreducible closed subsets of $Y$ are $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$, these sets are mutually disjoint so clearly, the only maximal chains of irreducible closed subsets of $Y$ are
$$\{1\} \subsetneq Y \quad \text{and} \quad \{2\} \subsetneq Y.$$
Thus $\dim Y = 0$, note that since $Y$ itself is NOT irreducible we also have that the only irreducible closed subsets of $X$ are $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$, so again the only maximal chains of irreducible closed subsets of $X$ are
$$\{1\} \subsetneq X \quad \text{and} \quad \{2\} \subsetneq X.$$
Thus $\dim X = 0$.

Comment: the only maximal chains you can fit in Y are $\emptyset \subsetneq \{1\} \subsetneq Y$ and $\emptyset \subsetneq \{2\} \subsetneq Y$ and similarly the only maximal chains you can fit in X are  $\emptyset \subsetneq \{1\} \subsetneq X$ and $\emptyset \subsetneq \{2\} \subsetneq X$ since Y is not irreducible.

Comment: It certainly seems to me that $\langle\emptyset, \{1\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,2,3\}\rangle$ shows that $\mathop{dim}(X)\geq2$...

Comment: {1,2} is not irreducible as it can be written as $\{1\} \cup \{2\}$ which are proper closed subsets.

Comment: The  definition of irreducible on page 3 includes non-empty, so $dim(Y)  = 0$

Comment: But then also $\text{dim}(X) =0$ so the problem persists.

Comment: You can just use `$\dim$` to produce $\dim$ without doing any \text or \operatorname stuff. I've fixed that plus cleaned up a few missing MathJax bits for you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your definition is incorrect. Here's the definition from page 5 of the text:

> If $X$ is a topological space, we define the *dimension* of $X$ (denoted $\dim X$) to be the supremum of all integers $n$ such that there exists a chain $Z_0\subset\cdots\subset Z_n$ of distinct irreducible closed subsets of $X$.

The issue is you've stuck $X$ on the end and required $Z_n\subset X$ to be a proper inclusion, which is not correct.

---

Let's check the example you proposed doesn't actually contradict the exercise.

It's a quick check that the listed subsets form a topology: they contain the whole space, the empty set, and they're closed under finite unions and arbitrary intersections.

The irreducible subsets of $X$ are $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, and $\{1,2,3\}$. Therefore $\{1\}\subset \{1,2,3\}$ is a chain of proper inclusions of nonempty irreducible subsets and there are no longer chains, showing that $\dim X=1$.

The nonempty closed subsets of $Y$ equipped with the induced topology are $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, and $\{1,2\}$. The only irreducible closed subsets are $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$, so $\dim Y=0$ and this is not a counterexample.

---

To show that exercise I.1.10(d) of Hartshorne is fine as written, here is one solution:

Let $Y\subset X$ where $X$ is irreducible, finite dimensional, and $Y\subset X$ is closed. By exercise I.1.10(a), $Y$ is also finite dimensional, so one can pick a chain of inclusions of irreducible closed subsets of $Y$ $Y_1\subset\cdots\subset Y_n$ demonstrating the dimension of $Y$. This chain of inclusions is also a chain of proper inclusions of irreducible closed subsets of $X$: since $Y$ is closed in $X$, the $Y_i$ are too; since the $Y_i$ have the induced topology, they're also irreducible subsets of $X$. Now look at the extended chain $Y_1\subset\cdots\subset Y_n\subset X$. From the assumptions that $\dim Y=\dim X$, we see that we must have $Y_n=X$ as $X$ is irreducible, and therefore $Y_n=Y=X$ as we have an inclusion $Y_n\subset Y\subset X$.

Comment: Yes this fixes everything, the only issue I have now is that my prof's notes include the condition that $Z_n$ is a proper subset of X so I'll talk to my professor about that.

Comment: @Daniel if this resolves your question, [please consider accepting the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

The definition of dimension given is not correct. The space $Y$, which is just the two point discrete set, ought to have dimension $0$.

With the index convention here:
[Dimension of a Noetherian topological spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707151/dimension-of-a-noetherian-topological-spaces)

you get that $Y$ has dimension $0$ and $X$ has dimension $1$, so  there is no contradiction.

I haven't got a copy of Hartshorne with me so I'm not sure what his index conventino is.

Comment: So if we omit the empty set then $\text{dim}(Y) = 0$ but then also $\text{dim}(X)=0$ how do you figure that the dimension of the whole space is 1?

Comment: @Daniel It's not about omitting or including the empty set. In $X$ you still have the chain $\{x\} \subset X$ of irreducibles which has longer length than a chain of irreducibles in $Y$ (this would also be true without a nullset). In your definition this matters because you get credit for the top guy even if it isn't irreducible, but this is not the case in the definition that is linked.